# Override virsh network from xml file to apply custom dnsmasq options outside

Tags: kvm-virtualization, xml, virsh

I want to automatically add a DNS CNAME entry using [the dnsmasq namespace](https://libvirt.org/formatnetwork.html#elementsNamespaces). Since this seems too complex to be handled by `virsh net-edit`, my idea is to use `virsh net-dumpxml`, apply the modifications and re-import the network. While the export works, the import throws an error.

```
$ virsh net-update --xml network.yml
error: command 'net-update' requires <network> option
error: command 'net-update' requires <command> option
error: command 'net-update' requires <section> option
```

It seems that `net-update` doesn't work that way, so I tried it with `net-create`

```
$ virsh net-create --file network.yml
error: Failed to create network from network.yml
error: Requested operation is not valid: network is already active as 'mynet.internal'
```

According to the help, there is no switch to override an existing network.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that the network was active - so I disabled it with *destroy*:

```
$ virsh net-destroy mynet.internal
```

After that, it's problemly possible to override the existing network (without any additional switches) using `net-define`

```
$ virsh net-define network.yml
```

Using `virsh net-dumpxml mynet` I could verify that my changes from the XML file were applied.

Answer (score 0):

Virsh commands handle network characteristics and can be used in conjunction with brctl commands to establish extra virtual bridges in your KVM setup. To reset it or override, shut down a guest, reboot a guest, and force a guest to stop.